# How to set the previous array value before entering the function?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

When a variable has been processed in a function, the array value of the variable changes forever. can you set the variable value back to normal? in this case I use a function to sort random data from an array. There's my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
  int temp = *xp;
  *xp = *yp;
  *yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, j, min_idx;

  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    min_idx = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
      if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
      {
        min_idx = j;
      }
    }
    swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
  }
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, key, j;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    key = arr[i];
    j = i - 1;

    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
    {
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      j = j - 1;
    }
    arr[j + 1] = key;
  }
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
      {
        swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
  int pivot = arr[high];
  int i = (low - 1);

  for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
  {
    if (arr[j] <= pivot)
    {
      i++;
      swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
  }
  swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
  return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
  if (low < high)
  {
    int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

    quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
    quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
  }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
  int i, j, k;
  int n1 = m - l + 1;
  int n2 = r - m;

  int L[n1], R[n2];

  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
  {
    L[i] = arr[l + i];
  }
  for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
  {
    R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
  }

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = l;

  while (i < n1 && j < n2)
  {
    if (L[i] <= R[j])
    {
      arr[k] = L[i];
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      arr[k] = R[j];
      j++;
    }
    k++;
  }

  while (i < n1)
  {
    arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

  while (j < n2)
  {
    arr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
  if (l < r)
  {
    int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

    mergeSort(arr, l, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

    merge(arr, l, m, r);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int select;
  char req;

  int arr[] = {20, 45, 30, 25, 15, 50, 100, 55, 10, 25};
  int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  do
  {
    system("clear");
    cout << "--- Sorting Menu ---\n\n";
    cout << "1. Selection Sort\n";
    cout << "2. Insertion Sort\n";
    cout << "3. Bubble Sort\n";
    cout << "4. Quick Sort\n";
    cout << "5. Merge Sort\n\n";
    cout << "Choose (1/2/3/4/5) : ";
    cin >> select;

    switch (select)
    {
    case 1:
      system("clear");
      cout << "Selection Sort\n\n";
      cout << "Random data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      selectionSort(arr, arr_size);
      cout << "Sorted data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      break;
    case 2:
      system("clear");
      cout << "Insertion Sort\n\n";
      cout << "Random data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      insertionSort(arr, arr_size);
      cout << "Sorted data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      break;
    case 3:
      system("clear");
      cout << "Bubble Sort\n\n";
      cout << "Random data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      bubbleSort(arr, arr_size);
      cout << "Sorted data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      break;
    case 4:
      system("clear");
      cout << "Quick Sort\n\n";
      cout << "Random data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      quickSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
      cout << "Sorted data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      break;
    case 5:
      system("clear");
      cout << "Merge Sort\n\n";
      cout << "Random data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
      cout << "Sorted data : ";
      printArray(arr, arr_size);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    cout << endl
         << endl;
    cout << "Back to menu ? (Y/n) : ";
    cin >> req;
    if (req != 'Y' || req != 'y')
    {
      system("clear");
      cout << "Exit from this program...\n\n";
    }
  } while (req == 'Y' || req == 'y');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No.  Once you change an array, it is not possible to get back the original array unless you somehow know all the operations done, and are able to undo the effects of each one, in correct (usually reverse) order.  Computers are not magical, so don't do that sort of thing unless you code specific logic that is needed.   A common approach is that, before calling the function, code creates a copy of the array and, after the function returns, copy the elements of the copy back to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a variable has been processed in a function, the array value of the variable changes forever. can you set the variable value back to normal?

Simply copy them before calling any functions:

```
std::vector<int>(arr_size) arr_copy;
std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::begin(arr_copy));

switch (select)
{
case 1:
  system("clear");
  cout << "Selection Sort\n\n";
  cout << "Random data : ";
  printArray(arr, arr_size);
  selectionSort(arr, arr_size);
  cout << "Sorted data : ";
  printArray(arr, arr_size);
```

and then copy them back afterwards:

```
  std::copy(std::begin(arr_copy), std::end(arr_copy), std::begin(arr));
  break;
```

Comment: You're most welcome - of course you can refactor that copy back to just after the `switch` statement.